# Azure ACS with ADFS Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, adfs, acs, ws-federation

We have a scenario where we have a single application that will be accessed from our organization and also accessed from a outside organization.  We will be hosting this web application in azure.  I am using MVC 5 with the Owin WSFederation Middleware. I can connect to my Local ADFS Server and it works as expected.

```
           app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Wtrealm = "https://localhost:44321/",
                MetadataAddress = "https://sso2.xxxxx.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml"
            });
```

When I use ACS as the Main STS and set up our ADFS server as an IDP, it routes to the correct ADFS login page, but once I authenticate I get  this error

**ID4037: The key needed to verify the signature could not be resolved from the following security key identifier 'SecurityKeyIdentifier**
   (
   IsReadOnly = False,
   Count = 1,
   Clause[0] = X509RawDataKeyIdentifierClause(RawData = MIIC4DCCAc...'. Ensure that the SecurityTokenResolver is populated with the required key.

```
           app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Wtrealm = "https://localhost:44321/",
                MetadataAddress = "https://xxxxxxxx.accesscontrol.windows.net/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml"
            });
```

I feel like this is an issue because the Federated metadata contains the key for the signature and since the owin middleware only has the metadata from the ACS the signer can't be determined.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the realm configured in ACS?

If I was implementing this, then i would probably use ADFS instead of ACS for my Home Realm Discovery because ACS is on it's way out.

I would configure Azure as an additional Claims provider in ADFS and only have my application using ADFS.

You also get a little more control around what the HRD pages look like.

Comment: The Realm is configured in ACS, I think the problem is that when the token comes back from one of the IDP's the signing token key was defined in the metadata xml. The application is pointed to the ACS's metadata xml so it has does not have any knowledge of the actual signing key of the IDP.

Comment: The Idp will provide a token to ACS which ACS will consume. ACS will then issue a new token and that token will be signed by the ACS cert.
During Application load OWIN should pull down the metadata from ACS and should have all the required information, including the Key. You should use something like HTTPFox to trace exactly what your browser is doing.

Comment: The IDP redirects directly to the application not back to ACS,  I took your suggestion and just used ADFS and setup a claims provider, but of course  I have the same problem with the IDP defined in the Claims Provider. I seem to be missing the step where the Claims Provider sends the Token back to ADFS for ADFS to redistribute the token to the  application.

Comment: Sound like the Endpoint in ACS is wrong then. Change it to https://youradfsfqdn.com/adfs/ls/